# Customizing a password strength validator plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, jquery-plugins

I am using a plugin called `pStrength.jquery.js` and for some reason its not submitting the form I have, or it is submitting the form even if it is not supposed to (when I changed the code)

The code i am using is:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#myForm').submit(function () {
        return false;
    });

    $('#myElement1, #myElement2').pStrength({
        'changeBackground': false,
        'onPasswordStrengthChanged': function (passwordStrength, strengthPercentage) {
            if ($(this).val()) {
                $.fn.pStrength('changeBackground', this, passwordStrength);
            } else {
                $.fn.pStrength('resetStyle', this);
            }
            $('#' + $(this).data('display')).html('Your password strength is ' + strengthPercentage + '%');
        },
        'onValidatePassword': function (strengthPercentage) {
            $('#' + $(this).data('display')).html(
                $('#' + $(this).data('display')).html() + ' Great, now you can continue to change your password!');

            $('#myForm').submit(function () {
                return true;
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Someone has told me that I should use booleans and inside the validation checks, set it to true or false.

The problem is that i have no idea how to do this

Is there anyone that could help me and show me the code to do this?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Have you checked the console to check for any errors which are preventing the form submission?

Comment: Perhaps you should ask the 'someone' what they meant. It seems very vague to me.

Comment: Does the form submit as intended if you comment out the first `$('#myForm').submit()` part? The one immediately after `$(document).ready()`

Comment: RoryMcCrossan I have checked the console, there are no errors no, Mike I have tried he is nowhere to be found and usually my colleague takes care of the javascript but he is off sick today so I'm stuck with it. @irot i have tried that, it submits then even if it shouldn't it is supposed to only submit when the passwords are atleast 60% strong according to the defaults specified in the documentation, yet it is being submitted even if my password strength is at 10%, thanks for the help guys

Comment: The documentation I'm using is located at [link](https://github.com/M1Sh0u/pStrength)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it was still submitting was because the `onValidatePassword` function runs on each individual field, whereas you actually had two fields to validate. If one field validates and the other doesn't, the form would still submit because the Boolean had already been set to true, which was the only condition needed to submit.

Updated code below, you can also refer to [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/irot/dspf9vuq/).

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#myForm').submit(function (event) {
        // TODO: check that the two field values match as well
        if ($('#myElement1').data('valid') === 'yup' &&
            $('#myElement2').data('valid') === 'yup') {
            // remove these three lines to make it submit
            alert('Submitting...');

            event.preventDefault();

            return false;

            // and uncomment this one line
            //return true;
        } else {
            event.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
    });

    $('#myElement1, #myElement2').data('valid', 'nope');

...
```

Your complete `onValidatePassword` callback should now look like this:

```
'onValidatePassword': function (strengthPercentage) {
    $('#' + $(this).data('display')).html(
            $('#' + $(this).data('display')).html() + ' Great, now you can continue to change your password!');

    formValid = strengthPercentage >= 60;

    // set for each element
    if (strengthPercentage >= 60) {
        $(this).data('valid', 'yup');
    } else {
        $(this).data('valid', 'nope');
    }
}
```

Comment: this seems to work a little better, the only issue is that it is now submitting as soon as it becomes valid so the user is still busy typing. is there any way around that so that the form only submits once the submit input is clicked? thanks for the help

Comment: Sure! Updated my answer to remove the `submit()` trigger, see if this fits your needs.

Comment: it is now submitting even is strengthPercentage is less than 60, I'm not sure if i declared it in the right place, i have put it just above $('#myForm').submit(function () {
    return true;
});

Comment: That's weird. I've updated my answer for clarity, but if you want to be extra safe you could try casting the strengthPercentage using `parseInt(strengthPercentage)` to make sure it's being compared as an integer as well.

Comment: Hi @irot still the same issue and i have checked, strengthPercentage is indeed an int, would you like me to create a page and send you the link so you can see it for yourself?

Comment: Sure. Just keep it to a bare minimum, please :)

Comment: Thanks @irot please see [link](http://www.legacyhotels.co.za/beta/test_password.cfm) I've made it as basic as possible and also added the defaults into the script

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `onValidatePassword`, you're binding to the submit event, instead of submitting the form. Replace this code:

```
$('#myForm').submit(function () {
   return true;
});
```

with

```
$('#myForm').submit();
```

Comment: thanks for the contribution, but if i do that it does not submit at all, any ideas?

Comment: @NOCLMRecipies Try removing the first submit handler which returns false.

Comment: if i do that it submits even when it shouldn't